# Can we merge csv column data to notepad existing dataset with specific ID?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Text file dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Dy1NFyfh8iPdoLPLVdpu-r9RZyCZwzt/view?usp=sharing

where PMID is there so I need to merge with this Citation number which is in the CSV file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VNbJnHuvrc3GNhELmLYXMk3mwML4P7N9/view?usp=sharing

Text data is

```
PMID- 20301691
STAT- Publisher
DA  - 20100320
DRDT- 20210311
CTDT- 20000204
PB  - University of Washington, Seattle
DP  - 1993
```

Now CSV data is

[image: mycsvfile.csv]

I need to append all this data with specific PMID

so desired output will be

```
    PMID- 20301691
    Citation - 1   "I want to append this data with matching PMID"
    STAT- Publisher
    DA  - 20100320
    DRDT- 20210311
    CTDT- 20000204
    PB  - University of Washington, Seattle
    DP  - 1993
```

How it will be working with multiple datasets where it is found PMID and append it.

I have try with this code

```
import pandas as pd
  
# reading two csv files
data1 = pd.read_csv('sepsis.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('mycsvfile.csv')
  
# using merge function by setting how='inner'
output1 = pd.merge(data1, data2, 
                   on='PMID', 
                   how='inner')
  
# displaying result
print(output1)
```

It's merging code but not same pattern as desired output.

Comment: Please do show text files as TEXT, not as images, and not as external links.  (see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use pandas to merge. You can just get the PMID and leave the rest of the file alone:

```
import pandas as pd
data2 = pd.read_csv('mycsvfile.csv', index_col=0)

with open('sepsis.csv', 'r') as f:
    line1 = f.readline()
    pmid = line1.strip().split(' ')[1]
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('sepsis_new.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(line1)
    f.write('Citation - %d\n' % data2.loc[pmid, 'Citation'])
    f.write(''.join(lines))
```

*NB. I didn't download your files to test*

Comment: It's showing error It doesn't get Id number

Comment: KeyError: '20301691'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: